# why every common lisp returns what's being defined

Tags: common-lisp

I'm wondering why every common lisp function/macro definitions returns what's being defined? It could return nil or the function itself. Why return the defined symbol? Is there anything I could do about it?

```
> (defun foo ()) => foo

> (defmacro bar ()) => bar
```

Comment: > Is there anything I could do about it? -- Wrap in another macro? I can't tell *why* is this the behaviour that exists, but returning `nil` seems even less useful to me. I can't really think of much else useful you can return from `defmacro` either...

Comment: > Is there anything I could do about it? - What problem is this behaviour causing? If we new that we could help more

Comment: @Baggers It's just out of my curiosity. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would expect that every defining form in Lisp either returns the name of what has been defined (like in `DEFUN`) or the object that has been defined (like in `DEFCLASS`).

That's a useful value which later can be used. In a Lisp interaction, the variable `*`, `**` and `***` have the last values. Thus you can do in a Lisp with interpreter and compiler:

CLISP:

```
[1]> (defun foo-with-a-long-name (a) (+ a 42))
FOO-WITH-A-LONG-NAME
```

compiling the function is then just:

```
[2]> (compile *)
FOO-WITH-A-LONG-NAME ;
NIL ;
NIL
```

No errors. Let's see the disassembly:

```
[3]> (disassemble *)

Disassembly of function FOO-WITH-A-LONG-NAME
(CONST 0) = 42
1 required argument
0 optional arguments
No rest parameter
No keyword parameters
4 byte-code instructions:
0     (CONST&PUSH 0)                      ; 42
1     (LOAD&PUSH 2)
2     (CALLSR 2 55)                       ; +
5     (SKIP&RET 2)
NIL
```

Okay, looks good.

Answer (score 2):

The reason every form returns something is how it's made by design. In a read-eval-print-loop this is useful so you get a confirmation even when it's not used.

What is returned is not important other than CL have it [specified](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defun.htm) in its specification so that every CL is doing the same.

Remember it's only in the REPL it displays whats returned. When you run a script, only things you print will display.

The other main dialect, Scheme, is said not to return anything when it mutates.. How it really is is that implementations return a special object that only the REPL ignore. If you (display (set! X 6)) you will get something printed.

Comment: you are guessing, there is nothing in the CL spec that gives this reasoning.

Comment: @RainerJoswig If we can agree that the CLHS is the specification, then it's specified that the [function name is to be returned](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defun.htm).

Comment: There is nothing in the spec that it means something - for example a 'confirmation'.

Comment: So you don'rt think CL conform to the [CLHS](http://clhs.lisp.se/) rather than something else, then what?

Comment: Try to find the word confirmation in the spec... all it has specified is that DEFUN returns the name. But not any meaning for it. Also it is not specified that Lisp can't display anything if it sees a DEFUN, while loading or compiling a Lisp file.

Comment: @RainerJoswig The mentioning of the spec concerned only that it was no coincident that the name was returned even if the return value was of no practical importance. For implementations that doesn't support running a source as a script, use other means of not getting output. The spec doesn't have to specify this because any implementations that don't can't be used for running programs.